# Prototype cell does not navigate push to next view controller Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I created the single view application using storyboard.
I have viewcontoller.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>


@end
```

I have viewcontoller.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSArray *recipes;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView :(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection :(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];

}
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"RecpieCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell ==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}

@end
```

In storyboard file, i have three view controller

> 1-navigation controller 2-Recipe Book View Controller 3-View
>   Controller

Prototype cell of the table view of Recipe Book View Controller is connected through push segue to View Controller.Is the problem Recipe Book View Controller does not navigate to View Controller?

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZqtA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVOKd.png)

Comment: Your screen shots don't show the action for the tableview row; If you select "Table View Cell" the segue should be linked to the "action" in the inspector.  Is this the case?

Comment: on click of cell do you want to navigate to Viewcontroller ?

Comment: yes...From this link you can download the sample for correction https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpybdmtov7i0wne/RecipeBook.zip?dl=0

Answer (score -1):

Just do a manual segue. Do you know how to do that? ctrl drag from one view controller to another. Give it an identifier.

Then override the function "didSelectRowAt indexPath". In there, call performSegue.